# JTextfield in JTabbedPane oversized

Tags: java, swing

```
    textArea = new JTextArea(textString);
    JScrollPane text = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
```

And I add the JScrollPane text to a JTabbedPane, nothing special.

However the texfield expands and resizes the entire window when I switch tabs.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    main.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
    textArea = new JTextArea(textString);
    JScrollPane text = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.add("Text lines", text);
    tabs.add("Another", new JPanel());
    main.add(new JLabel("test"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    main.add(tabs, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setContentPane(main);
    frame.pack();
```

Comment: and your question is....

Comment: I don't want the window to stretch when I deselect the tab obviously.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How do you add your JTabbedPane to the hierarchy? Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and an explanation on what you would expect

Comment: Added a working example.

Comment: The 'working example' is not an SSCCE as requested by @GuillaumePolet.  Who are you replying to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that I found with your example is that when you enter many lines in the text area and switch to another tab, then the tabbed pane grows in size. In order to fix that, just enter how many text area rows you want to be display in the `JTextArea` constructor. For example, to display 5 rows:

```
textArea = new JTextArea(textString, 5, 0);
```

Now the tabbed pane will not get resized.